# Page numbers only appear on pages where a chapter starts

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, chapters

I have a problem in the number of the pages in my report the problem is that the number of the page appears in the beginning of the chapter but in the next page it is absent. This is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor} %les couleurs
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\include{title-content}
\include{dedicaces-content}
\include{remerciement-content}
\color{black}
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Introduction générale}

Foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can format your code by indenting with 4 spaces or by clicking on the `{}` (curly braces) icon above the edit window, just as I did. `:)` If you have inline code, this link could be useful: [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using `\pagestyle{empty}`, so you're telling LaTeX to remove the page numbers; however, in starting chapter pages, the page style LaTeX uses is `plain`. Remove `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a `\pagestyle{empty}` instruction that does precisely that: it removes anything from page headers and footers.

The default for the `report` class is `\pagestyle{plain}`, which simply adds the page number at the center of the footer and is always used in the starting chapter pages.

So the solution is to remove `\pagestyle{empty}`.

---

If you don't want any page number in the front matter, then using `\pagestyle{empty}` is not sufficient, as every `\chapter` command will use `\pagestyle{plain}` in the page where the chapter title is, including the table of contents and the list of figures or tables.

I'm not keen to not having page numbers in the front matter, other than in a dedication page. However, this is solvable.

I'll use a reduced preamble just to show what you can do; add the packages you need.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%<insert here the packages you need>

\makeatletter
\let\latexps@plain\ps@plain
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{\let\ps@plain\ps@empty\pagestyle{empty}}
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \let\ps@plain\latexps@plain\pagestyle{plain}%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\input{title-content}
\clearpage
\input{dedicaces-content}
\clearpage
\input{remerciement-content}
\clearpage

\doublespacing

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction générale}
```

In this way all pages in the front matter won't have any number; the numbering will start at 1 for the first chapter.

---

Unrelated, but important: add `\clearpage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, because this command doesn't start a new page. I'd use `\input` rather than `\include` for the front matter material (adding `\clearpage` when a page break is wanted).

Comment: but when I put \clearpage before \pagenumbering{arabic}  the number of page appear in the table of content and the list of figure and I don't like this.

Comment: @BoutheinaGherib Please, state more clearly where you want and don't want page numbers. You will have page numbers in the first page of the table of contents no matter if `\pagestyle{empty}` is there or not.

Comment: I want that the number of page start in the introduction all  the pages before the introduction I don't want that contain the number this is the code    {\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\include{title-content}
\include{dedicaces-content}
\include{remerciement-content}
\color{black}
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents


\listoftables
\listoffigures
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\mainmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction générale}
}

Comment: @BoutheinaGherib The code I added should be what you need.