# The pages of the generated PDF are not printed, except on the first page of each chapter

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage, pagestyle

I am working on the template for a thesis I have been commissioned to adapt, and I have an unusual problem with the page numbers, they do not print except on the opening page of the chapter.

I did some research and found that various packages can cause these anomalies, and I found that there are several packages that can potentially interfere with the correct page numbering in LaTeX. Here are a few examples:

`fancyhdr`: This package allows for customization of headers and footers, including page numbering. If not configured properly, it can cause issues with the correct placement or formatting of page numbers.

`titlesec`: This package provides tools for customizing section headings, but if used incorrectly, it can affect the placement of page numbers.

`hyperref`: This package enables hyperlinks within the document. If not used carefully, it can sometimes cause problems with page numbering, especially when combined with other packages or document classes.

`geometry`: This package allows for customization of the page layout, including margins. If the margins are set improperly, it can affect the positioning of page numbers.

`setspace`: This package is used for adjusting line spacing. If the line spacing is set inconsistently or to a very large value, it can disrupt the alignment of page numbers.

The legacy code was messy and used these packages, which I have used before without this problem. I opted to redo the template with KOMA Script in the hope that the problem would disappear in the new document, but it remains.

The legacy code was messy and used these packages, which I have used before without this problem. I opted to redo the template with KOMA Script in the hope that the problem would disappear in the new document, but it did not.

I searched for previous questions about it here, of course. I came across several, including [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79770/page-numbers-only-appear-on-pages-where-a-chapter-starts#79776) which is the closest to my problem; however, as I don't use the empty page style, it doesn't solve my problem, which is why I'm writing this.

A (not so) MWE might be the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
  fontsize=12pt,% 
  captions=tableheading,% 
  headings=small,% 
  headings=openany,%
  headsepline=off,% 
  headinclude=on,
  footinclude=off,% 
  titlepage=off,% 
  twoside=off,% 
  parskip=half+,% 
  bibliography=totoc,% 
  draft=off% 
}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{%
   a4paper,%
   left=1.5in,%
   right=1in,%
   top=1in,%
   bottom=1in%
 }
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[super]{nth} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
{}% space above
{}% space below
{\itshape}% body font
{\parindent}% indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\newline}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{properties}{Properties}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem*{facts}{Facts}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{result}{Result}[section]

\usepackage{mathtools}
% New commands for abs and norm (needs mathtools for work)
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{inconsolata}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{% 
  detect-all,% 
  output-decimal-marker = {.},%
  group-minimum-digits = 4,%
  range-units = brackets,% 
  list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },% 
  list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },% 
  range-phrase={\,a\,}% 
}
\usepackage{bigints} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{TuftePage}{RGB}{255,255,248}
\definecolor{TufteText}{RGB}{17,17,17}
\definecolor{Burgundy}{RGB}{128,0,32}
\definecolor{Vivid}{RGB}{159,29,53}
\definecolor{Old}{RGB}{67,48,53}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
    format=hang,%
    labelformat=simple,%
    labelsep=period,%
    textformat=period,%
    justification=RaggedRight,%
    singlelinecheck=false,%
    font=small,%
    labelfont=bf,%
    %margin=1.5\parindent,%
    width=.8\textwidth,%
    twoside,% 
    position=auto,%
}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  %bookmarks    =true,%
  unicode       =true,% 
  pdftoolbar    =true,% 
  pdfmenubar    =true,% 
  pdffitwindow  =false,% 
  %pdfstartview ={FitH},% 
  pdftitle      ={},% 
  pdfauthor     ={},% 
  pdfsubject    ={Master Thesis},% 
  pdfcreator    ={LaTeX with Overleaf},% 
  pdfproducer   ={LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2021)},% 
  pdfkeywords  ={} {} {} {} {} {} {} {},% 
  pdfnewwindow  =true,% 
  colorlinks    =true,% 
  linkcolor     =Vivid,% 
  citecolor     =Old,% 
  filecolor     =Old,% 
  urlcolor      =Burgundy% 
}
\usepackage{xurl}

% Further custom format
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[autooneside=true]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\pagestyle{plain}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\centering\color{Vivid}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{Burgundy}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\hspace{\parindent}\color{Old}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\itshape\hspace{\parindent}\color{TufteText}}
%\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{dedication}{\raggedright\large}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\usepackage{tocbasic} 
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[% 
    linefill=\quad,%
    raggedpagenumber,%
    pagenumberbox=\hbox% 
   ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 

\def\indeq{\qquad{}\!\!\!\!}

\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{layout}

\raggedbottom 
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000 

\pagecolor{TuftePage}
\color{TufteText}
\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{TufteText}{\oldtextbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
% Title page
%\maketitle
\mainmatter
% Abstract
\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\Blinddocument 
\end{document}
```

The idea is that the pages should be printed on one side of the page, that there should be no header, only the page number centred in the footer, that all pages of the front matter should have no header or footer, no page numbers and that the page count in Arabic numerals should start from the abstract onwards.

I've been trying everything I can to solve this problem, but I can't find anything that works for me. I thought that with the `scrlayer-scrpage` package I could solve it, but it didn't work.

The strangest thing is that the previous template made it impossible to add headers to the page, and the page numbers were also complicated to handle. However, there is no `.cls` file nor `.sty` that could be behind this.

Comment: A MWE should at least show the problem, yours doesn't. Copy your example in a new document in a new  empty folder and try it before you post it.  And once you have an example that shows the problem, try to shorten it, to get something that at least can claim to be a bit more minimal.

Comment: why post so much code when you know no one can run it as it  has `\include` of files not provided, and if asking about page numbers why have all that unrelated code about captions or whatever?

Comment: We know that the first page of a chapter uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`, while the default page style for scrbook should be `headings`.  Search your code for any occurance of `\pagestyle`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischerI have tried it with several documents in the project, this is the most minimal example I have. I put all the preamble because I already made tests all day and nothing worked for me, I didn't know what to discard for the same reason, sorry. I will take your advice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I was exhausted, after 14 hours of working on this project non-stop, I was sleepy, tired, and I didn't realise that I didn't change the content of the document before sending my answer. In short, I'm human, and I make mistakes, I'm sorry I caused you an annoyance with this.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You are quite right, in theory that is how it works and that is what I know about the default `\pagestyle`. 

But it doesn't work for me in this case and that's why I dared to ask the question, the code you mention is the same one you see in the preamble. So if you find the line where the `\pagestyle` is defined, please tell me where it is because yesterday I looked for it all day, and I was unable to find it. Moreover, I put it explicitly and as it didn't work I left it commented, as you can see. I know I'm not seeing something, but I don't know what it is, so I ask.

Comment: @Aradnix I wasn't annoyed just commenting that the question as posted couldn't be answered. The example is still far far too long. You can check if the problem occurs if you remove `\usepackage{listings}` and if the package is not needed delete it and repeat. You are asking people to trace tex's behaviour and including 100 packages you do not need in the example just makes that harder.

Comment: The example gives the error `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'definition' defined.`

Comment: If I scroll past that error I get a 14 page pdf with a page number on every page

Comment: There is still too much code in your example. Moreover there is still the error, David already has told you, and if I pass over the error, all 14 generated pages have page numbers. So the example still does not show the issue and therefore is useless. Off-topic: You don't need to load `tocbasic`, because `scrbook` already does. And it is recommended to set at least `fontsize=…` as option of `\documentclass` already.

Comment: Off-topic: Because you refer to `titlesec` and `fancyhdr` in your question, please note, that using them with `scrbook` could break several KOMA-Script features.

Comment: Noting your trouble, and with a close in mind soon, I suggest to apply the tree-like 50:50 strategy as illustrated here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 at least for the preamble. // I.e. comment out "one half" of the packages etc., and may be some follow-up "deletes" needed to compile and see, what comes out. Repeat for the other "half". One, or even both, will cause trouble. Repeat the strategy on the troubeling "half" (which becomes a "quarter" etc.), which narrows down problematic parts quickly. // However, changing order is almost not treated this way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because looking at the comments the problem seems to be hard to both replicat and isolate with the code shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your observations and comments. I made some adjustments to the code after reading them, but I doubt they will do the trick. 

In the end, I took Ulrike's advice, created a new project in Overleaf with all this and magically made it work as expected. I still can't find the cause of the error and as this desperate question doesn't contribute anything, I think it's best to delete it.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks for the remarks about `tocbasic` and font size in KOMA, if I understood correctly, font size should be the last of the options within `\KOMAoptions`, correct?

Comment: @cabohah As for your second comment, it seems to me that there is a misunderstanding. I said I researched the packages that could cause the problem I asked about, and listed the most popular ones. And to rule out possibilities, I opted, as usual, to use `KOMA Script` instead of the standard classes, so I save myself from loading `titlesec` or `fancyhdr` because I know that `KOMA` doesn't work well with them.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you very much, I think this is the most remarkable thing, I was unaware of this method, but it may be useful for future cases and not fall into despair as now.

Comment: @Aradnix `fontsize` should be set with the option list of `\documentclass`. Setting it with `\KOMAoptions` should be done only, to change the base font size inside the document. See, e.g., the note: *“even the KOMA-Script classes themselves do not recalculate all lengths if the main font size
changes after loading the class”* in the description of `fontsize` in the KOMA-Script manual. Similar for `parskip`. IMHO `\KOMAoptions` generally shouldn't be needed or used for the basic settings of a document.

Comment: @cabohah Years ago, I read here that it was preferable to use `\KOMAoptions{}` to configure class options rather than global options, as usual. Do you know if there is any mention of this issue in the KOMA Script documentation? I'm confused between that recommendation and what you're telling me now.

Comment: @Aradnix I've already give you a quote from the KOMA-Script manual. Where did you find, that `\KOMAoptions` is preferable. Maybe this could be valid for some special cases, but as a general principle this is not valid and IMHO more or less nonsense.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks for your helping, I'll read the documentation again because I know you gave me the quote, but I couldn't locate it in the version I have of the KOMA Script documentation which is dated 16 June this year. That's why I asked about it.

Comment: @Aradnix You can find the quote in the [current English manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#page.58) at the end of the first paragraph on page 58. And it is already in the documentation of option `fontsize` for several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer, but a diagnostic tool.  Add this redefinition of `\pagestyle` before loading any packages, then interrogate `\currentpagestyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\normalpagestyle=\pagestyle
\renewcommand{\pagestyle}[1]{\xdef\currentpagestyle{#1}%
  \normalpagestyle{#1}}
  
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \currentpagestyle
  
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \currentpagestyle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, as I said in the question, Ulrike's suggestion to create a new project worked perfectly for me. I still don't know what the fuck causes this behaviour, but for future cases, I will follow your advice, thank you very much.